# ASP.NET AJAX and Session Variables

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, session

I have an ASP.NET (VB.NET) application with 2 pages, a 'main' page and a second 'data-only' page whose only purpose is to be an AJAX data target for the main page, making a database call and rendering the results for a jQuery (AJAX) .get().  I'm using a session variable in the main page that I want to test for the existence of in the data-only page before it makes its DB call and renders the data.

I've tried doing this directly and it fails.  From what I've been able to determine so far, the data-only page is unable to detect the session variable until its session is officially started (somehow using session_start, apparently).  If this is correct, how do I start a session in the data-only page when it is only accessed via AJAX calls from the main page?  I definitely need the data-only page to be session variable-aware.  Thanks!

-- Rick

Both pages are ASP.NET. I added a label to the main page to validate (on page_load and on submit of the session value) that the session variable exists and what it is. The data_only page returns a yes or no message (it's always no) if it detects the presense of the session variable.

Page Code - main.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="main.aspx.vb" Inherits="main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="but_1" runat="server" Text="Add Session Variable" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_1" runat="server"></asp:Label><br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="but_2" runat="server" Text="Get Data" />
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#but_2').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.get("data_only.aspx", function (data) {
                    $('#lbl_2').text(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Code-Behind - main.aspx:

```
Partial Class main
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call Check_Session()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub but_1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles but_1.Click
        Session("var1") = txt_1.Text
        Call Check_Session()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Check_Session()
        Dim strSession = Session("var1")
        If strSession Is Nothing Then
            lbl_1.Text = "No Session variable."
        Else
            lbl_1.Text = "Session Variable = " & strSession
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Page Code - data_only.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="data_only.aspx.vb" Inherits="data_only" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Code-Behind - data_only.aspx:

```
Partial Class data_only
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim strSession = Session("var1")
        If strSession Is Nothing Then
            Response.Write("No session variable.")
        Else
            ' Database call occurs here
            Response.Write("Success! Get data here.")
        End If
        Response.End()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what is the type of your 'data-only' page? Aspx? IHttpHandler?

Comment: The code as example will be help...

Comment: Both appear to be just regular ASPX pages. It appears that both have *access* to the session, but the session is not *initialized* with the data you are expecting when starting from the data page. Is that correct?

Comment: Code added above.  I have 2 questions, really..  Why is data_only.aspx unable to detect the session variable which has been created (by main.aspx) prior to the AJAX call, and  2) Is there a technique that I can use to make data_only.aspx session-aware so that it can work as intended?  Thanks!

Comment: @Charlie.. I'm not sure what you mean by session initialization. To my thinking the session has already been started and the session variable created by using the top button on main.aspx. If so, I'd expect that session variable to be recognizable by data_only.aspx when the AJAX call is made. It isn't.

Comment: BTW.. I'm using IE 8 for this exercise, it that matters.

Comment: @Charlie.. Clarification: data_only.aspx is called only via AJAX from main.aspx. There is no step in this process that involves the opening of data_only.aspx in a browser window.

Comment: I just pasted your code into a new project and it works for me (data_only.aspx retrieves the Session variable successfully). The only thing I can see that's visually different is that my "Inherits" attribute (in the Page directive) says `Inherits="WebApplication2.main"` (and similar for data_only). In other words, they include the project name. Though that may be because of how my solution is set up.  What version of Visual Studio are you using?  And what version of the .NET Framework is your project targeting?

Comment: I'm using VS 2010 Pro and targeting .NET 4.0.

Comment: Partial solution:  I added a Global.asax file to the app and set Session("var1") = "" in the Session_Start block.  This successfully established var1 for both main.aspx and data_only.aspx.  Good.

The interesting part is that I then changed the variable using the button on main.aspx.  Clicking the 'Get Data' (AJAX) button returns the originally initialized value (from Global.asax), not the new value.  It would seem that there is some sort of session awareness latency with AJAX calls.

Comment: Another oddity..  If I open main.aspx in a new tab in the same browser window the revised session variable is displayed on main.aspx AND upon clicking the second (AJAX) button.

I'm sure that this is all consistent with some set of rules that govern the lifespan of session variables but it sure doesn't make any sense to me right now.

Comment: I'm targeting 3.5 and I don't experience any issues with the code you've shown - it just works.  What happens if you change to target 3.5?  Also, don't forget to use "@" notifications to make sure people see your replies (you can type @jadarnel27 in a comment here to get my attention, for instance).

Comment: @jadarnel27..  Thanks for the suggestion - no joy with 3.5 for me. This one's just a beast.  I may just have to abandon client-side as the data-call solution in this case.  Bummer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try using a "master class" for both pages i.e both pages inherit from your master class (which in turn from Inherits System.Web.UI.Page) that has all the session handling logic.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify and narrow the scope, all .aspx pages are session aware by default and I'm pretty sure that this is not your problem.

First of all make sure that you are using the correct url for the GET call from Ajax, and you can make sure of that by using Chrome developer tools (Network tab) and observer the exact url that Ajax calls. Maybe you need to add "/" before your page url or you need to specify the folder name if it's not in the same folder, like: "/otherFolder/page.aspx".